# Get id of record when create data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails app i'm creating some data and save it in db, but now i need to get id of record (when saving). I need to get this id, and for this record, in other table create array of record binded for this id (in model i have associations).

```
  PriceList.create(:distributor_id => distributor_id, :brand => brand, :article_nr => num_catalog, :price => price, :quantity => quantity, :waittime => waittime)

class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cross_lists
  belongs_to :distributor
end




class CrossList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price_list
end
```

It could see as two questions in one, but major is first part.

Comment: Why do you want to assign the primary key? This is a very unsafe operation. Or do you mean you want to give your new `pricelist` a `distributor_id`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Show the models and choose better wording and description, please.

Comment: assign it to some variable say x and u can get id using x.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to set

```
class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cross_lists
  accept_nested_attributes_for :cross_lists # <- this line
  belongs_to :distributor
end
```

and then pass the data for cross_lists in an array.

```
PriceList.create(:distributor_id => distributor_id, 
                 :cross_lists_attributes => [
                   {...},
                   {...}
                 ]
                )
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

If you don't have your associated models at hand, nor their properties, you can create them on the fly after saving/creating the main record.

```
@price_list = PriceList.create(...)
if @price_list.persisted?
  # now the @price_list object has an ID

  @price_list.cross_lists.create(...)
  # one CrossList record has been created, and its price_list_id
  # field has been automatically populated
end
```

Comment: main trouble is in that, i don't know how much records there will be for on pricelist_id, so :cross_lists_attributes => [
                   {...},
                   {...}
is not good choise...

Comment: see edited answer for example on how to build associated objects.

Comment: it will iterate this creating when i have more than one record to write?

Comment: If you want to iterate, use an iterating construct. I don't know your data, nor your constraints, so you can't expect me to tell you exactly what to do. I showed you a way to create a `CrossList` instance already associated to a persisted `PriceList` instance. You are in charge to loop into whatever data you have to create your objects.

Comment: if simple: i need to add to crosslist some data, which will be assotiated with pricelist, but i could be one record for one id, or many

Comment: You will get the data to add somehow. You are not being very explicit on it. When you have the data, **for each record** to create, just **do** `@price_list.cross_lists.create(...)` with the wanted data.

Answer (score 0):

Why is that array of record bound to that id not a collection of your price list? This way it will all be done automatically and you don't need to worry about that.

```
class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base

  ....
  has_many :records
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :price_list
end
```

now you can do stuff such as:

```
PriceList.create(:distributor_id => distributor_id, ....., :records => [Record.new, Record.new])
```

it's much more easy for you, since you don't have to worry about assigning ids and adding transactions. ActiveRecord takes care of that for you.

But to answer to your first question: you don't have an id until the record is stored in the db. So, for you to get the id with your code:

```
rec = PriceList.create(:distributor_id => distributor_id, :brand => brand, :article_nr => num_catalog, :price => price, :quantity => quantity, :waittime => waittime)
rec.id #=> returns the id from db
```